# How to fix lighting inside a room

Tags: lighting

What I have done in terms of lighting is pretty ok but I want the bookshelf to be highlighted a bit more and other parts of the room to come into view a little bit more but just enough to be noticed. The center of the project is the light coming in from the window and it should not be taken over.

[Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/7c726ee9a67640c8bb4a1237aec77652)

What i have right now:
[image]

Comment: just change the rendering to cycles, turn on denoising and you will get: https://imgur.com/3L9lR9W

Comment: I want the bookshelf to be highlighted a bit more while also preventing it from taking too much attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Eevee

For this of kind lightning you have to add **Irradiance Volume** object and under *Render Properties > Indirect Lightning > Bake Indirect Lightning*.

[image]

Notes:

- your dimensions of object is huge (chair 40 m) ... you can select all and scale it down or go to Scene Properties > Units and change it to something like 0.02 to result with something closer to reality
- usually is used Sun light type (but I see it penetrates walls too much and I don't know how to avoid) always helps to ad Solidify modifier to walls
- to avoid unwanted volumetric penetration change Render Properties > Volumetrics > **Start** to 4 **End** to 10, **Distribution** 0.8

[image]

### Cycles

Same setup (irradiance is not used off course) ...

[image]

If you need brighter interior, there is more things you can try, but just increasing light Strength seems to be enough.

[image]

Comment: Actually I use cycles not eevee so please help me with that

Comment: So why do you use screenshot in your Q from Eevee? If you use Cycles please share actual image and mark what is wrong with that (edit your Q to be more clear). Thank you

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just did

Comment: Great :) Thanks for Q update ... if answer solved your issue consider mark as accepted so other can see it from main list https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you keep this site organised.